# how to clean a ngrx store when logged out

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-reducers

I want to clean all my states in the store after logging out .
this is my reducers/index.ts

```
export interface AppState {

}
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
router: routerReducer
};
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<AppState>[] = !environment.production ? [storeFreeze] : [];
```

my app.module.ts

```
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers:[]})
```

beside i already has my auth reducer(authState) with two actions login and logout

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://medium.com/@moneychaudhary/how-to-reset-the-state-or-clear-the-store-on-logout-in-ngrx-store-d2bd6304f8f3.

Answer (score 0):

I create a meta-reducer  function  in my index  that  when user logged out it will clear the store

```
export function clearState(reducer) {
  return function (state, action) {

    if (action.type === Auth.AuthActionsTypes.LogoutAction) {
      state = undefined;
    }

    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}
```

and then added it in my app.module

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers:[clearState]})
```